# Icon/Glyph Suggestions to represent "Manufacturer Information"

Tags: website-design, icon, glyphs

I'm working on making an ecommerce site responsive, and as part of that, I'm replacing text in several tabs with appropriate icons when viewed on a small screen.  One specific tab I'm struggling to find an appropriate icon for is the tab for manufacturer information on product pages.

Thus far, the best thing I've been able to find is the trademark ™, but I'm not especially happy with the final result, so I'm looking for other suggestions.

Comment: What kind of products are being sold? I could see some kind of tools icon, possibly placed over something representing the information part, like an "i" or instructional booklet. Some examples of the direction I'm talking about: [**1**](https://thenounproject.com/term/maker-space/21038/), [**2**](https://thenounproject.com/term/tools/75549/), [**3**](https://thenounproject.com/term/design/112465/), [**4**](https://thenounproject.com/term/design/112465/).

Comment: The site sells specialty sporting goods equipment.  
I had been hesitant to use tools since they are frequently used to represent configuration options, but I went back and tried some options based on your suggestion. Staying within Font Awesome, their wrench icon combined with a smaller circled "i" seems to convey what I'm going for, so if you repost as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Alright. Done and done. No problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I commented on the original post I could see some kind of tools icon, possibly placed over something representing the information part, like an "i" or instructional booklet. Some examples of the direction I'm talking about: [1](https://thenounproject.com/term/maker-space/21038/), [2](https://thenounproject.com/term/tools/75549/), [3](https://thenounproject.com/term/design/112465/), [4](https://thenounproject.com/term/design/112465/).

Now, knowing that the site sells specialty sporting goods equipment I think you can customize it for that even further. Maybe the aforementioned tools could be something more sports related, at least one of them, something easily understandable that relates to the manufacturing of sports products.

Anyway, hope that helps. Would love to see you post here what you end up going with (if at all possible).

Comment: Thanks again.  Here's a screenshot of a product page viewed in the mobile layout. There are a few other things I'd like to change/fix, but as the only designer AND only developer on staff for a nationwide (if heavily seasonal) retailer, I only have so much time. Regardless, the tabs in question are snapped to the bottom of the layout:
[Screenshot](http://imgur.com/g5LZFWK)

Answer (score 1):

a factory silhouette with an "i" in the middle?

a document/open book (like a catalog)?

If the tab is product-specific, why not just use the information circle with an i inside it? Or replace the tab with an information button next to the item title.

Answer (score 0):

Why not mix in another framework? I find semantic-ui to be much easier and superior to bootstrap. They also have a much wider range of icons.

http://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html

Take a look at that page in particular under maps there is an icon called building. This might work well to represent an organisation.

If you have any issues with this leave me a comment and I will provide you with an example when I am back at my computer.

Apologies for any formatting issues in this answer it was written on my mobile.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your contribution! OP never said anything about using bootstrap. Also, if all he needs is a single icon then it's better to take them from the source, which in this case is [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). I think your answer could be even better if you link to the specific icon your suggesting from that icon set.

Comment: I'm actually already using Font Awesome for most of the icons on the site ;)
Nothing I saw quite conveyed "Brand" or "Manufacturer" to me. I did consider using the "building" icon, but when I tried it and tested with coworkers, multiple people read it as "store" and expected to find location or product availability information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using font awesome, can't you use something like the 'List' icon?

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/list/